vitest stubbing URL gives "Not implemented: navigation (except hash changes)"
I am using jsdom with vitests and trying to mock URL.createObjectURL. Currently, I am using the following:
vi.stubGlobal('URL', {
  createObjectURL: vi.fn()
})

The above works good and my tests passes, however, I am getting the following error on the console:
stderr/__tests__/mytest.js
Error: Not implemented: navigation (except hash changes)

Although the tests are not failing, what should be done to get rid of this error?
